# Force C++ class instances to change member value when copied or assigned

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have a class named `Solution` defined as below.  I have only included the relevant code, and I have **not** written a custom copy or assignment operator.

```
class Solution {

public:

    Solution() {
        stream.setNewSeed(seedShift+static_cast<long>(12345));
        ++seedShift;
    }

    RandomNumberStream stream;

private:

    static long seedShift = 0;
};
```

The point here is that I want each new instance of `Solution` to have a different random number stream.  This works.

The problem, however, is that there are some places where I am copying an instance of `Solution` from a `std::vector<Solution>`, modifying it slightly, and then pushing the copy onto the same `std::vector<Solution>`.  When this happens, I have two instances of `Solution` with the same random number seed, and disaster ensues.

How can I cause the `stream.setNewSeed(seedShift+static_cast<long>(12345));` and `++seedShift;` statements to be run in the copied `Solution` instances that are pushed onto the vector?

Comment: You say you have not written either of those. Why not?

Comment: Because I'm a novice, and not sure if those are what is needed... though I suspected they might be.  If they are needed, I don't know how to write them

Comment: You need to implement the copy constructor with the same operations as the default constructor.

Comment: But, when I implement the copy constructor, do I need to write code to cause all the other class members (not shown above) to be copied?  FYI: I don't have any pointers as members, so deep copy (or whatever it's called) shouldn't be needed here.

Comment: Well it depends on what kind of members you have but you can write  a common function that does the common operations and call that from both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload the assignment operator.  Note - this also means the random number seed will also change again when you read the value out of the vector and/or copy the vector itself.

```
class Solution {

public:

    Solution() {
        stream.setNewSeed(seedShift+static_cast<long>(12345));
        ++seedShift;
    }

    Solution& operator=(Solution& other)
    {
        stream.setNewSeed(seedShift+static_cast<long>(12345));
        ++seedShift;


        x = other.x;
        y = other.y;
        z = other.z;


        return *this;
    }

    RandomNumberStream stream;

private:

    static long seedShift = 0;
};
```

Comment: Suppose there are other member variables, like `int Solution::x`.  Then, would I need to write code inside the custom copy constructor in order to copy the value of `Solution::x` when I copy the `Solution` instance?

Comment: @synaptik - absolutely yes.

Comment: OK, so there's no simple way to _add_ code to the default copy constructor.  If you want non-default behavior in any way, you have to fully define everything that happens when copied.  Correct?

Comment: Working with `vectors` will generally require either `MoveConstructable` or `CopyConstructable`. You want to implement the Copy Constructor here; the assignment operator is arguably less important, although should be implemented to retain the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing into a `vector` will use the copy constructor (or move constructor, but we'll make it simply and assume it uses the copy constructor for now). This has the signature:

```
Solution(const Solution& rhs);
```

You can then implement the logic for this fairly simply:

```
Solution(const Solution& rhs)
{ 
     stream.setNewSeed(seedShift + 12345L);
     ++seedShift;
}
```

Note if you implement this, you should probably implement the copy assignment operator as well:

```
Solution& operator=(const Solution& rhs)
{
    if(this != &rhs) {
        stream.setNewSeed(seedShift+static_cast<long>(12345));
        ++seedShift;
    }
    return *this;
}
```